# Why does querySelectorAll work using data-xyz on jsPerf but not in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute, jsperf, selectors-api

I'm playing around with `jsperf`, `querySelectorAll` and `data-xyz` attributes.

Here is my current jsperf: [jqmData vs. attribute selector](http://jsperf.com/jqmdata-vs-attribute-selecotr/4)

The critial piece is in the `js` test:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('data-role')
```

Note I'm not using any square brackets [] and it still runs fine and beats all other selectors flat. I upped it to 200+ data-role elements on a page, and it still worked faster.

Then I tried on my own test page [here](http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/test.html) (see Firebug) and alas... the nodeList is empty when I omit without square brackets.

**Question:**
What magic is jsperf using, so that the selector works there and not on my dummy website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests don't check that the selector actually matched anything. No great surprise that `querySelectorAll` won when it knew there weren't any `data-role` tags and so could immediately return an empty `NodeList`. :-)

And indeed, if you add checks to each test to make sure it really got the right number of elements, the `querySelectorAll` one fails: http://jsperf.com/jqmdata-vs-attribute-selecotr/5

Comment: @frequent: I've added an update jsperf showing that the `querySelectorAll` one isn't working.

Comment: Mine is on [version6](http://jsperf.com/jqmdata-vs-attribute-selecotr/6). Thanks!